# How do I prevent DevExpress POCOViewModel design-time from calling bound web services?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I have a DevExpress `POCOViewModel` containing the following property declaration:

```
public virtual List<Group> Groups
{
    get
    {
        return api.GetGroups();
    }
}
```

The `virtual List<Group>` property is bound as the ItemSource for a ComboBox, and the `api.GetGroups()` method calls an external web service. When I'm making changes in design time, the api method is called.

Is there any way to avoid this? Am I using the MVVM pattern incorrectly?

Comment: I believe that the answer is provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757646/how-do-i-stop-my-viewmodel-code-from-running-in-the-designer

Comment: Thanks, have added a close vote.