# Show hidden WPF elements in Visual Studio designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visibility, designer

As opposed to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322520/hide-wpf-elements-in-visual-studio-designer), does anybody has figured out a way to show all hidden elements while working in Visual Studio designer(or Blend)?

It's anti-productive to constantly change the default visibility property of elements to be able to see them while editing Xaml files.

Comment: You can do this a number of ways, I prefer design time data contexts as it prevents writing code in the viewmodel for supporting the design/development. That said, it can lead to more code overall.

Answer (score 0):

After researching, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757646/how-do-i-stop-my-viewmodel-code-from-running-in-the-designer). So here's a tested solution that can be implemented in the view model :

```
//Declare default Visibility values
private Visibility _processBarVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
private Visibility _buttonVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;

public ViewModel()
{
    //In constructor, override Visibility values if in design mode
    DependencyObject dep = new DependencyObject();
    if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(dep))
    {
        _processBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        _buttonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```